# Approach to Insert only new records and exclude insertion of deleted records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in executing the insert in a table using the below query I insert records in `hConn` table

```
--Insert Into Conn table
INSERT INTO hConn
 (hp10_id, hp09_id, hp_e_id,hp_s_id, hp_createddate, hp_updatedate,hp_insertby,hp_updateby)
 
SELECT 
p10_id, p09_id, e_id,s_id, Getdate() AS hp_createddate, Getdate() AS hp_updatedate,
'1' AS hp_insertby,'1' AS hp_updateby
FROM   p10_table
       INNER JOIN p09_table
               ON p10_p09_id = p09_id
       INNER JOIN s_table
               ON s_p_id = p10_id
       INNER JOIN e_table
               ON p_s_id = p10_id
WHERE 
       e010_lan_code = 'EN'
       AND e009_lan_code = 'EN' 
EXCEPT
SELECT hp10_id, hp09_id, hp_e_id, hp_s_id, Getdate(), Getdate(), 1, 1
FROM   hConn 
GO
```

After this step, I delete 2 records from hConn using below statement

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
          FROM   hConn 
          WHERE  hp10_id = 15 
                 AND hp_e_id = 48 
                 AND hp_s_id = 4) 
  BEGIN 
      DELETE FROM hConn 
      WHERE  hp10_id = 15 
             AND hp_e_id = 48 
             AND hp_s_id = 4 
  END 


IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
          FROM   hConn 
          WHERE  hp10_id = 11 
                 AND hp_e_id = 48 
                 AND hp_s_id = 4) 
  BEGIN 
      DELETE FROM hConn 
      WHERE  hp10_id = 11 
             AND hp_e_id = 48 
             AND hp_s_id = 4 
  END 
  
  GO
```

Next time on execution of the insert script, I do not want these 2 records to be inserted in `hConn` table and only want those records which are new in `select` query of the insert script but on execution of statement, the 2 deleted records also get added, I somewhat do not want to add them in the `hConn` table again.
Is there any other approach to solve this issue instead of deleting the records every time?

Is it correct to store the deleted records in another table and check it before insertion in the `hConn` table?

Comment: You can include a condition in WHERE clouse of INSERT to filter those data out.

Comment: Add a bit column `Deleted` and set it. Then filter it out everywhere except here.

Comment: @DaleK I was thinking about the same approach but I have been told it is not a good design

Comment: @Serg It can be the case that there can be more such records which I will need to delete in future hence not sure if this should work for me

Comment: @the_coder_guy who told you that? Its an extremely common design, it provides full traceability which is often very important these days. I use it all the time.

Comment: Brent Ozar is very well respected, maybe whoever told you will listen ? [what-are-soft-deletes-and-how-are-they-implemented](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/02/what-are-soft-deletes-and-how-are-they-implemented/) You might always want to track who did the delete? And maybe even when? All optional of course.

Comment: @DaleK Yeah sure will check on this with the architect. Also is there any chance if I can use another table use the MERGE statement to combine two tables?

Comment: You can use an archive table... thats another approach, has its pros and cons, its often more complex to maintain, but can perform better. Or if you database is big enough you can partition on the deleted column.

Comment: Okay thanks will check if I can do anything with the archive table approach.

Comment: As an aside: you do not need the `IF EXISTS` checks. Just run the `DELETE`. It's an unnecessary extra step to check first - because the `DELETE` does that anyway (it will either delete the rows if they exist, or affect zero rows if there are no records that match the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way is to use a cursor and fetch a row then check conditions for deletion then create a delete sql if the condition is met